# Are Indian, Pakistani, and Bangladeshi Muslim students banned in the USA after Trump's executive order?

Tags: usa, student-visa

Are Indian, Pakistani, and Bangladeshi Muslim students banned in the USA after Trump's executive order?

If **NO**, is there any problem they are going to face studying in the USA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are Indian, Pakistani, and Bangladeshi Muslim students banned in the USA after Trump's executive order?

Not yet.  As of now, the travel ban applies only to citizens of Iran, Iraq, Libya, Somalia Sudan, Syria, and Yemen.  However, there have been suggestions in the media that the list may be expanded.

> Is there any problem they are going to face studying in the USA?

I assume here that you mean to ask if there is any problem related to immigration status (and excluding personal problems that could apply to anyone, like being denied entry for a criminal history or the like).  The answer is that it's not possible to say.

The list of seven countries could be expanded to include India, Pakistan, or Bangladesh.  It's also possible that the executive order will be nullified by the courts.  If that happens, it's possible that a new executive order could be put in place.  Almost anything could happen, really.

It's therefore not possible to say whether students from India, Pakistan, or Bangladesh might be subject to adverse US immigration policies in the near future.